# When i try to calculate 2 power n when n above 30 i get 0, how can i fix it?

Tags: java, pow

for my home work i need to write code to calculate 2 power n (2^n)
while i managed to make it work for n from 0 to 30, for 31 i get -2147483648
and for any n above 31 (33,35,40..) i just get 0.. how can i take care of it?
i need to use simple commands i cant use math pow

public class Task3a {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //---------------write your code BELOW this line only!--------------
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = myScanner.nextInt(); 
    int expo = n ;
    int base = 2;
    if (n==0){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    if (n==1){
        System.out.println(base);
    }
    else{
        while(expo>1){
            base = base * 2 ;
            expo = expo - 1;
        }
        System.out.println(base);
    }
    //---------------write your code ABOVE this line only!--------------
}
```

}

as i said , for an example for 2^35 i get 0

Comment: you are crossingg the range of int in java use BigInteger instead if want to work with large numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to use the primitive `long`. The primitive `int` has a limited value of 2^(+/-)31 so it is defaulting to zero once it has that limit.

Comment: First, why can't you use `long`? Second, any fixed-width integer representation will have an overflow point, so you have to code for that regardless. Are you allowed to code to prevent possible bugs?

Comment: Is it just `long` you cannot use? Could you consider using other primitive types, you can find a list of them in the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Can you clarify what your other limitations are?

Comment: You can't store 2^-31 in an int. Or 2^31, for that matter. The range of int is -2^31 to 2^31 - 1.

Comment: iam in they university first year computer science and they want us to use only int
and use mathematical solutions

Comment: this task was to calculate only for n between 0 and 30 so this code is fine
but next task was to print  (2^n)%k
for any n even above 30
they gave us this hint: ( ⋅ )% = ((%) ⋅ (%)) %k

Comment: ok solves it :)
used : else{
   while(expo>1){
    base = (base * 2)%k ;
    expo = expo - 1;
   }
  }
  int answer = base ;
  System.out.println(answer);

Comment: Can you edit your question with the second task and hints etc so we can see the whole picture please

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigInteger` . So `2^35` is:

```java
        BigInteger base = new BigInteger("2");
        int power = 35;

        BigInteger answer = base.pow(power);

        System.out.println(answer.toString());
```